# Serverless API Gateway Logging

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-serverless

To anyone who can help,

I am trying to get serverless aws API gateway logs to work but no joy, I have multiple endpoint and when i deploy the code the log groups in cloudwatch for each endpoint is created but not logs or log streams are created when i query the endpoints. Code below for one endpoint where the logging is defined.

I have noticed that under the stages in the aws api gateway -> logs/tracing doesn’t have enable cloudwatch logs clicked. When i manually click on this, logging then works but to a generic cloudwatch log group.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: us-west-1
  apiGateway:
    restApiId:
      “Fn::ImportValue”: SharedGW-restApiId
    restApiRootResourceId:
      “Fn::ImportValue”: SharedGW-rootResourceId
  logs:
    restApi:
      accessLogging: true
      format: ‘requestId: $context.requestId’
      executionLogging: true
      role: arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/Test-Logs-Gateway
      roleManagedExternally: true
      level: INFO
      fullExecutionData: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be importing the API gateway, you should add that configuration where you create the api gateway.

Comment: And what if the API gateway already exists or is build using another tool, like Terraform?

Comment: you need to update at the source, serverless uses cloudformation and if I am not mistaken wont be able to update it  because didn't create the resource.

Comment: In our case we are creating the API with Terraform and are able to add methods and endpoints using serverless. We are also able to change documentation etc. But only logging does not seem to be supported when the API is not created by serverless/CloudFormation.

Comment: Why not consider the deploy with open api spec instead of serverless?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and you should check which was which Aws API type you're using, as how logs are enabled are slightly different between if you're using REST API or HTTP Api. In my case I was using the rest syntax when I needed to be using the http syntax

```
  logs:                 # Additional logging configuration - This will create an additional log file in cloudwatch
    httpApi: true       # Enables logs for Aws HTTP Api Gateway - Ref: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api#access-logs
#    restApi: true      # Enables logs for Aws REST Api Gateway - Ref: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#logs
```